# Show search option in Applozic conversatin tab

Tags: applozic

I am using applozic sidebar plugin with following code.

> window.applozic.init({appId: applozicApplicationKey, 
>           userId: currentUser.userId,
>           userName: displayName,
>           imageLink : userImage,
>           email : currentUser.emailId,
>           contactNumber: '',
>           desktopNotification: true,
>           notificationIconLink: 'assets/images/vw-purple-logo-sm.png'
>       });

And opening chat box with code

> $applozic.fn.applozic('loadTab', '');

I want to show search option in conversation tab rather than contact list. 
How to achieve this?